# is there a way to get detailed information about HDD in linux

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, disk-usage, smart

In 2013 I used a program that analyzes the HDD and gives detailed and deep information about the hard disk. However, that program, [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/en/), only works on Windows.

Is there a GUI that is similar to the CrystalDiskInfo which displays the information based on the S.M.A.R.T characteristics?

I am looking specifically for the life time hours to estimate how many hours did the laptop work.

I am running Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia 64-bit - MATE 1.18 on my DELL inspiron 1546

Comment: Other than `smartctl`?

Comment: have not tried smartctl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there’s [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/), which provides a GUI showing the SMART information from all the drives attached to the system it’s run on.

In Mint it’s packaged as `gsmartcontrol`.

Comment: Thanks !!    it is pretty close and gives clear information except for life time hours.  Anyways, thumbs up  :)

Comment: It does show lifetime hours, see “Power-On Time” in the attributes.

Comment: ohh, that is nice, I got it.